Keep only rows that have at least one null
I am trying to do basically the opposite of drop_nulls(). I want to keep all rows that have at least one null.
I want to do something like (but I don't want to list all other columns):
for (name,) in (
    df.filter(
        pl.col("a").is_null()
        | pl.col("b").is_null()
        | pl.col("c").is_null()
    )
    .select("name")
    .unique()
    .rows()
):
    print(
        f"Ignoring `{name}` because it has at least one null",
        file=sys.stderr,
    )
df = df.drop_nulls()


Start with: df.sum_horizontal(df.all().is_null())

The print statement suggests that you ignore all rows with at least one null value. The question asks for the opposite.

@Hericks Sorry, the print statement is confusing. I want to keep the rows that have a null, to print them (and indicate what are the rows that I will ignore with drop_nulls().

It sounds like you are looking for pl.Expr.any_horizontal. The following will keep all rows containing at least one null value (in any of the columns).
df.filter(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null()))

